# UL/LI list item full-width

Tags: html, css

I have a list item that is dynamically created. Like this:

```
<ul class="record-top-btns">
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can create full-width `ul/li` with that. Like:
[image]

**Note:**

- The code should work in IE8
- we don't know number of `li` item because they are dynamically created

my CSS code:

```
.record-top-btns{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

.record-top-btns a{    
    padding:2px;
    color:#5c5c5c;
    display:block;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

.record-top-btns li{
    display:table-cell; /* will not work in IE8 */
    background:#e3ffca;
    text-align:center;
    background:white;
}
```

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqXH5/)

Comment: i doubt you can handle `dynamic` things with `css`, if old IE versions are to be considered....u *have* to opt for jquery!!!

Comment: Yeah i think i should Handle that with `JS`

Comment: @Radian For a non JS solution that works in IE8, how about using `table` and you dynamically create `td` instead of `li`- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqXH5/5/)?

Comment: @Vucko I'm Looking for a `UL/Li` solution but If a solution is not found then I'm Inevitably use `table`

Comment: Just count the number of elements using the server-side script of your choice and generate the needed "dynamic css"

Comment: Hm, thats odd... IE8 supports `display:table-cell` -> [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-table) and [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) so this has to work. Maybe something else is the problem in IE8. Try putting `display:table-row` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqXH5/8/)

Comment: @Radian : do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/Bk5vX/ ??

Comment: @Vucko thanks, yeah IE8 supported but the code not worked! also i'm try `table-cell` but not work

Comment: @Beginner No,the LI width should be expand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE8 you can use `text-align-last:justify` on the container and `display:inline-block` on the elements to achieve the evenly spaced effect - it just won't work in stable Chrome, so you'll need to make it a fallback with conditional comments so only older IEs use the `text-align` approach. For some reason IE also requires you to set `text-align` when setting `text-align-last` - keep that in mind.

[Sample fiddle which works in IE/FF](http://jsfiddle.net/LqXH5/12/).

Comment: i try your code but not working in IE8 , here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LqXH5/2/ «please check that in IE8 »

Answer (score 1):

going as per my comment, try `jQuery`, its much hassle-free

```
var li_count = $("ul.record-top-btns li").size();/* get number of li */
var wid = 100 / li_count; /*find li width */

$("li").css('width',wid+'%'); /* set li width */
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/438fP/)

Comment: `table-cell` is supported in IE8 and so is `jQuery`...i suggest you first clear the cache and then test!

Answer (score 0):

```
.record-top-btns {
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   background:#e3ffca;
}

.record-top-btns li{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#e3ffca;?? you have 2 different background colours coded
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqXH5/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
.record-top-btns{
  display:block;
  width:100%
  height:25px;
  background :#939393;
  }

 .record-top-btns li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto // if you want fit li in ul use width in percentage like width 33.3% when using 3 li 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code and this works in IE

```
  <div id="hbar">

      <ul class="record-top-btns">
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
     </ul>

  </div>
```

and the css code

```
 #hbar{
  width:100%
 }

 #hbar > ul > li{    
 float:left;
 }

 li{
 width:70px;
 }
```

here is the [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/reachdreamz/R8B7c/1/)

Comment: Please Note :`we don't know number of li item because they are dynamically created

`